# FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES with filter_var_array

Tags: php, zend-framework, sanitize

I’m trying to sanitize a formData but I want to keep the Quote.

```
$formData = filter_var_array($formData, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

I know There Is an options FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES to keep the quote.

I'm not able to use that options, i have tried a lot of different way.

```
$formData = filter_var_array($formData, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING|FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

It Always encode the quote or return false when i tried to put the options FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES.

What I’m I missing here? Tanks for your help

Comment: Can you give more information? Tag the language you are using and add the library you are using in the question

Comment: Hi, i add PHP and ZendFramework + an exemple of one of the way a tried

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING and FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES by a comma:

formData = filter_var_array($formData, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);